# Angular NGRX @Effect to catch all actions

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an angular app where I want a side effect to call a service to a 3rd party analytics platform.  My thought was to do

```
 Any action fires -> Side effect catches everything -> Service to call analytics
```

With that said, I obviously don't want to add that flow in every effect.  I just want a "catch-all" side effect at the top of the tree to catch any and all Ngrx actions, and instead of dispatching an action, to simply call the service.  I am having trouble with the syntax...

```
@Injectable()
export class AmplitudeEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}

  @Effect()
  private *any action here* = this.actions$.pipe( <--what to put here
    ofType(), <-- leave empty to catch everything?
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.amplitudeService.sendValues(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4).pipe(
        // catchError(error => of(new AmplitudeFailure(error)))
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Just commenting out ofType() function should do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good use case for an Effect, I also give this example in [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this-e0b2bd9da165).

To answer your question, you can just leave the `ofType` out of it:

```
  @Effect()
  log = this.actions$.pipe(
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.amplitudeService.sendValues(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4).pipe(
        // catchError(error => of(new AmplitudeFailure(error)))
      )
    )
  );
```

I'm not sure if you do want to catch the error, as this is just for logging purposes, so you could do:

```
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  log = this.actions$.pipe(
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.amplitudeService.sendValues(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the ofType and your error handling would just terminate the observable so ngrx would stop working so I added the right way to handle the catchError. I should look like that but since I dont know what sendValues does I figured that it would return an observable.

```
  @Effect()
  name = this.actions$.pipe(
      this.amplitudeService.sendValues(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4).pipe(
          map((x: any)=> x),
          catchError((error: any, effect: Observable<Action>) => {
            return effect.pipe(startWith(new new AmplitudeFailure(error)));
          }
      )
    )
  );
```